# How do you include timeframe in python pandas pair plot?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to display a pair plot using pandas. My dataset has 4 columns (Snapshot, Irradiance, Temp, Output Power). When I plot the pair plot, Snapshot does not appear. Can anyone help with this?

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')
dataset['Snapshot'] = pd.to_datetime(dataset['Snapshot'])
without_date=dataset['Snapshot'].apply(lambda d:d.time())
dataset['Snapshot']=without_date

print(dataset.head(5))

pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(dataset,marker='o',hist_kwds= 
{'bins':20},s=1,alpha=0.8,) 

plt.show()
```

[Screenshot of how the dataframe look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l41Yu.png)

[Screenshot of pairplot results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WPC0.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your attached images, I don't believe pairplot supports datetime(). Can you change 'Snapshot' as a continuous time series and try again?

Adding 'Snapshot' as a Pandas Series of integers should produce the results you want, regardless if its in datetime() format.

Comment: yes it does. I've just posted a screenshot of what I get when I use dataset.head()